# Align items of the listview with items from other layout

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, alignment

I have this layout with a table layout and four items inside:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
    android:background="#FF3538">

       <TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fecha"
         />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Vv"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Dv"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Ht"
        />

 </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this other layout (the listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/celda_cabecera" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
    >

       <TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/o3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dirviento"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/04"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
       />
</TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to align the items of the listview with the items of the first layout, but my solution not works fine

Comment: Have you understood your question....

Comment: the first layout is the header of the listview. i want align the items

Comment: You need to set fixed width for your views in order to align them......not wrap content

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Er_ i think you have to use the weight concept.

Just replace your all view under `<TableRow>` like below view.

Example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/o1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/fecha"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

So give same weight to all child view of `<TableRow>`

It menace i replace,

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Instead of

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```